# Values of $a$ and $b$ that maximize the value of $\int^b_a(x-x^2)dx$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

Values of $a$ and $b$ that maximize the value of $$\int^b_a(x-x^2)dx$$.

Let \begin{align}F(a,b)=\int^b_a(x-x^2)dx.\end{align}
Then, by Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
\begin{align}&\frac{\partial F}{\partial b}=b-b^2\\&\frac{\partial F}{\partial a}=-(a-a^2)\end{align}

Setting these to zero, yields $b=0 \;\text{or}\;1$ and $a=0 \;\text{or}\;1.$ Assuming that $a<b$, then $a=0$ and $b=1$ are the values.

**Please, I'm I right?** If not, can you please, provide a correct one?

Comment: A graphical intution can be made look at the graph of the function x-x² and see that if we proceed to the right from 1 we reduce the value of the integral and same for the left of 0 but for general and complex cases your approach seems fine to me

Comment: Are you adding $a \le b$ as a constraint?

Comment: @copper.hat: No, I'm not. I thought I could just make the assumption. Otherwise, I might not achieve a minimum.

Comment: @OmojolaMicheal: Well, without that restriction there is no $\max$ as such, for example, if you set $a=0$ and let $b \to -\infty$ then the value is unbounded above.

Comment: To use the first order conditions to find a $\max,\min$ one needs to know that there is a $\max,\min$ in the first place. In the above example, if one adds the constraint $a \le b$ then there is a $\max$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Can you please, explain why the integral is unbounded above if $a=0$ and $b=-\infty$?

Comment: $\int_0^x (x-x^2)dx = -{1 \over 3} x^3 +{1 \over 2} x^2$. Now let $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Okay, that's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right.

Another argument could be noticing that $x-x^{2}$ is a parabula with negative concavity that intersect the $x$-axis in $x=0$ and $x=1$ and consequentely the maximum value of the integral of the function $x-x^{2}$ is reached on the biggest interval in which the function is positive, that is $[0,1]$. Thus $a=0$ and $b=1$.